# Anchor linking with UI Router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I found [answers on here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18373005/5797650) (option 3) that indicated that by adding `target="_self"` to an href, you could do anchor linking with Angular. I tried this out, but my app uses Ui Router, and it appears that this option does not work, as on click I was getting a state change to my default route.

Is there a way to achieve anchor linking in a way similar to what is shown in the answer above, but with UI Router?

Comment: Hi @fun_hat did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ui-sref="page({name: 'name', '#': 'frag'})"` or `$state.go('page', {name: 'name', '#': 'frag'})` should do the trick.

Comment: I just tried the first one but it didn't do anything. Does it have to occur on a state change? I am trying to link to a different spot on the same page.