# Redirecting to specific part of a different page with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to redirect to a specific div in a page from another, I know this can be typically done by redirecting to the URL + appending # and the ID of the given div. However this seems to not be working for me, don't know if it's AngularJS rendering the element that's causing it.

The way I'm doing it is simply

```
<a href="/baseURL#divID" class="btn btn-default mt-5 font-italic">Register Now!</a>
```

Project is being developed with AngularJS and Sharepoint (don't know if this might also be a factor).

Comment: do you have angular routing? Because it uses same notation as html anchors to perform view changes. This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026537/anchor-links-in-angularjs

Comment: I don't have Angular Routing and my problem is that the div I want to redirect to is on a different page, problem is it seems like the div isn't rendered yet when the browser tries to move to it.