# Angular scroll to child position

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular.
I have 2 views, **one**:

```
<div class="block">
  <p>
    one works!
  </p>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and **two**

```
<div class="block">
  <p>
    two works!
  </p>
</div>
```

I have created some CSS:

```
.block {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

The idea is that **two** is a child of **one** but when you are on **two**, the content for **one** is still visible. This works with no issues.
The problem, is that when I navigate to **two**, the page still stays at the top. I would like it to scroll (animated if possible) to the top of the `<router-outlet>` or **two**.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, provide block two a unique id:

```
<div id="block-two" class="block">
  <p>
    two works!
  </p>
</div>
```

In your ts, call this code on click event:

```
document.getElementById('block-two').scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Where do I call that? in ngOnInit? Or ngAfterViewChecked or something else?

Comment: After navigation. How do you navigate? Is block two a component? If yes, then in its ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: You assigned the id to the outermost div? and write this line in ngAfterViewInit() of block two component

Answer (score 0):

You have to get help of html **anchor links** here.

Please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026537/anchor-links-in-angularjs) also